# Is it possible to change appMobi splash screen image before sending it off to the app stores?

Tags: cordova, appmobi

The subject says it all. Trying to see if I can't change that "loading" "splash screen" image to something more personal. If so how can I do that? I know somehow when I pack the image and send it off Im supposed to include the screen shot, splashscreen and whatever else, but not exactly sure how that works either. Anyone able to dumb it down for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. During the build process you are asked for all that info (including splash screens of particular resolutions for the target device). The wizards are pretty self-explanatory. To manage it all login at http://apphub.appmobi.com